# Arduino to Java data sent through USB

Tags: java, arduino, accelerometer, rxtx

I am trying to get Accelerometer data into my Java application from Arduino at its IMU. When I run my Arduino program on Arduino IDE and bring up Serial Monitor data flow is really good. Unfortunatelly when I try to run my Java code something strange happens. I have to wait for 10 seconds and then about 1000 lines appear immediately. Then i have to wait for another 10-20 seconds and another 1000 lines of data appears.. Is Arduino sending data in packages ? Can't I get a single value right after its given to me from IMU ?

Arduino code :

```
 #include <MPU9250.h>
 #include <quaternionFilters.h>

 #define AHRS true         // Set to false for basic data read
 #define SerialDebug true  // Set to true to get Serial output for debugging

 // Pin definitions
 int intPin = 12;  // These can be changed, 2 and 3 are the Arduinos ext int pins
 int myLed  = 13;  // Set up pin 13 led for toggling

 MPU9250 myIMU;

 void setup()
 {
   Wire.begin();

   Serial.begin(38400);

   pinMode(intPin, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(intPin, LOW);
   pinMode(myLed, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(myLed, HIGH);

   byte c = myIMU.readByte(MPU9250_ADDRESS, WHO_AM_I_MPU9250);
   if (c == 0x71) // WHO_AM_I should always be 0x68
   {
     myIMU.MPU9250SelfTest(myIMU.SelfTest);
     myIMU.calibrateMPU9250(myIMU.gyroBias, myIMU.accelBias);
     myIMU.initMPU9250();

   } // if (c == 0x71)
   else
   {
     while(1) ; 
   }
 }

 void loop()
 {
   if (myIMU.readByte(MPU9250_ADDRESS, INT_STATUS) & 0x01)
   {  
     myIMU.readAccelData(myIMU.accelCount);  // Read the x/y/z adc values
     myIMU.getAres();

     myIMU.ax = (float)myIMU.accelCount[0]*myIMU.aRes; // - accelBias[0];
     myIMU.ay = (float)myIMU.accelCount[1]*myIMU.aRes; // - accelBias[1];
     myIMU.az = (float)myIMU.accelCount[2]*myIMU.aRes; // - accelBias[2];
   } 

     myIMU.delt_t = millis() - myIMU.count;

     if (myIMU.delt_t>20) // waiting some time to get less data
     {
       if(SerialDebug)
       {
         Serial.println(myIMU.ay*1000);
       }


       myIMU.count = millis();
       myIMU.sumCount = 0;
       myIMU.sum = 0;
     } 
   }
```

Java code :

```
package perkusja;
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class Perkusja {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    System.out.println("Select a port:");
    int i = 1;
    for(SerialPort port : ports)
        System.out.println(i++ +  ": " + port.getSystemPortName());
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int chosenPort = s.nextInt();

    SerialPort serialPort = ports[chosenPort - 1];
    if(serialPort.openPort())
        System.out.println("Port opened successfully.");
    else {
        System.out.println("Unable to open the port.");
        return;
    }
    serialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

    Scanner data = new Scanner(serialPort.getInputStream());
            int counter =0;

    while(data.hasNextLine()){
        try{
                       // float kupa = data.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println(data.nextLine());
                        System.out.println("Line number : " + counter++);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("ERROR");}
        }
    }

}
```

I've been following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B6j_yr9H8g&t=392s

Im using Arduino ProMicro from sparkfun and IMU - MPU9250 also from sparkfun

Comment: Seems like your JAVA code is doing the blocking. What is the meaning of `SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING` in timeout setting?

Comment: You are right ! The Library SerialPort has changed since the video and this setting is doing something else now. I've set it to `serialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER` and then in Arduino I could even remove line `if (myIMU.delt_t>20)`. I can now send and gather all the data and it seems to be working perfectly. Thank you so much !